# History of operations in recovery mode

Tags: macos, recovery

As the title above, I'd like to know if there is a way to see all operations done in recovery mode in an iMac. For example, a command in the bash terminal of the recovery mode.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a way to investigate some other problem. Why not tell us what that is?

Comment: A person that i live with, created an admin account for himself without the password of the other administrators. What I think happened is that he went to recovery mode and reset all password (as a matter of fact I can't no longer access my personal account because the password is wrong, so the other admins). Once he did this he went inside an account and created his admin account. I wanted to find a way to prove it

Comment: You can put a firmware password on some Macs which would prevent access to Recovery. But if you can't trust someone you live with to use (or not use) other people's belongings respectfully, then your problem is more than technical.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no such history kept across reboots.

While you're still logged in, you can use for example the `history` command in `bash` to see the entered commands. However, as soon as you reboot, everything from that history is forgotten again.

Comment: What if i type "resetpassword" in bash and reset the password of all admins. Is there a way to see that this operation was done?

Comment: No, there's no log of that. What is the specific problem you're trying to solve here? - Note that on a modern Mac with FileVault enabled, you wouldn't be able to just run resetpassword to "commandeer" a Mac. Depending on configuration, you would need either to be able to login with the correct Apple-ID or to know the FileVault recovery key.